# Given n number of cells, is there a way to fill in n-1 cells and the n'th cell will autopopulate?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

Let's say n = 4.

If I have this raw data sheet containing this data:

---

```
Name | Food | Drink | Colour

Dave | Choc | Apple | Green
Kate | Peas | Cherry| Yellow
```

---

And I have this (in another sheet)

```
Name    | Food    | Drink   | Colour
(blank) | (blank) | (blank) | (blank)
```

How would I fill (say) the 1<sup>st</sup>, 2<sup>nd</sup> and 4<sup>th</sup> entry and then it matches the 3<sup>rd</sup> data entry from the raw data? (Note that it shouldn't matter which 3 cells I fill).

For example if I will it initially like this:

```
Name | Food | Drink   | Colour
Kate | Peas | (blank) | Yellow
```

Then Excel should automatically fill the drink entry with "Cherry".

Is there a way? Preferably without VBA but with VBA if need be.

Note: The order of filling shouldn't matter (i.e. I could have filled in the 1<sup>st</sup>, 3<sup>rd</sup> and 4<sup>th</sup> cell instead). (blank) indicates a literally blank cell.

Comment: What's the minimum number of new entries in 1 row before a lookup is performed?

Comment: n-1. So in this n=4 case, it'll need 3 entries in 1 row to get the 4th one.

Comment: Also another note: I found a way to do it when we *know* which $n-1$ cells are filled, and their column positions from: https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria

Comment: @Hereditary_Excel1,,  there are many methods like in Raw data sheet create one new column say Order,,, has 2 options Confirm/Pending,, write lookup  formula in another sheet,, if order Confirm then get the record,, then you may associate another field using exceljet method.

Comment: Hi Rajesh, I'm not sure what you mean. Won't it only work if we know which n-1 we have to fill? My query is about the case where we can fill *any* n-1 cells.

Comment: The simplest way is to use VLOOKUP() on "another sheet". Columns 2..4 contains formula which selects values from "raw data sheet" by entered name (1st column). Then you may overwrite the formula in column 2..4 with actual value iа it differs. Of course, the name in "raw data sheet" must be unique.

Comment: Do you mean that in each of the four entries have the lookup formula ready?  
Then overwriting the cells 2, ... , 4 with the actual data values and then column 1 entry should autopopulate?

Comment: to do "Excel should automatically fill the drink entry with "Cherry", You'll need vba. | to do "Preferably without VBA " > that's the answer I'm proposing.

Answer (score 0):

ref :  https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria

Assuming that these are in A1:D3 of Sheet1 :

```
Name | Food | Drink | Colour
Dave | Choc | Apple | Green
Kate | Peas | Cherry| Yellow
```

Then in Sheet2, assuming A1:D1 is the headers, put :

```
A2 -> =IFERROR(IF(ISFORMULA(B2)+ISFORMULA(C2)+ISFORMULA(D2),"",INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(1,INDEX((B2=Sheet1!B:B)*(C2=Sheet1!C:C)*(D2=Sheet1!D:D),0,1),0))),"")

B2 -> =IFERROR(IF(ISFORMULA(A2)+ISFORMULA(C2)+ISFORMULA(D2),"",INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(1,INDEX((A2=Sheet1!A:A)*(C2=Sheet1!C:C)*(D2=Sheet1!D:D),0,1),0))),"")

C2 -> =IFERROR(IF(ISFORMULA(B2)+ISFORMULA(A2)+ISFORMULA(D2),"",INDEX(Sheet1!C:C,MATCH(1,INDEX((B2=Sheet1!B:B)*(A2=Sheet1!A:A)*(D2=Sheet1!D:D),0,1),0))),"")

D2 -> =IFERROR(IF(ISFORMULA(B2)+ISFORMULA(C2)+ISFORMULA(A2),"",INDEX(Sheet1!D:D,MATCH(1,INDEX((B2=Sheet1!B:B)*(C2=Sheet1!C:C)*(A2=Sheet1!A:A),0,1),0))),"")
```

Then you can just drag downwards.

Fill (replace the formula by typing on it..) in any 3 cells. the last one will appear. I'm using the last method mentioned in the ref.

The catch : I had set it to show nothing if there is no match.. you can change it if you want.. ( the iferror() conditions )

Hope it helps. (tell me if it did't work) ( :